# Complex Conjugate intersections with axis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

$(2-i)z + (2+i)\overline{z} = 20.$  Where does this intersect the real axis?
Currently, I am thinking of going into the format of az+b$\overline{z}$ but I don't think this will bring me anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $z$ is real, then $z = \overline{z}$ and the equation becomes
$$
(2+i)z + (2-i)z = 20,
$$
i.e.,
$$
4z = 20.
$$

Hence the intersection with the real axis is $z = 5$.